# Topology question on first countable.

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, first-countable

This question was asked in the GATE MA 2023 paper:

**Q.44.** Let $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ be a topological space, where the topology $\tau$ is defined as $$\tau = \{U \subset \mathbb{R}: U = \emptyset \ or \ 1 \in U\}.$$
Which of the following statements is/are correct?

- **(A)** $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is 1st-countable
- **(B)** $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is Hausdorff
- **(C)** $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is separable
- **(D)** The closure of $(1,5)$ is $[1,5]$

I found that it is separable since it has countable dense set, but can't prove it is first countable or not, since 1 and empty set has uncountable neighborhood it implies it has at least countable neighborhood so it is first countable. can I use this logic?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: now its done, i didnt have 10 repu points so have to use link to add image

Comment: Could you clarify your reasoning on Q1? What does it mean that the empty set has an uncountable amount of neighbourhoods? Notice that $\emptyset\not\in\mathbb{R}$ which means that you can't treat it as a point of your toplogical space.

Comment: I'm still learning to use mathematical notations on website, thanks @C-RAM for updating  the post.

Comment: @DankaMakabre thank you for clarifying. ∅∉R and 1∈R.

Answer (score 1):

That's the [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) of $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. **It is first countable** since, for a given $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we know that $\mathcal{B}(x)=\{\{1,x\}\}$ is a neighborhood basis of $x$ (it doesn't matter wether $x=1$ or not). However **it isn't Hausdorff** since, for every $x\neq1$ and every neighborhood $N_x\in \mathcal{N}(x)$, we have that $\exists A\in\mathcal{T}:A\subseteq N_x\Rightarrow x,1\in A\subseteq N_x$ which means that, for every neighborhood of $1$ $N_1\in\mathcal{N}(1)$, we also have that $1\in N_x\cap N_1\Rightarrow N_x\cap N_1\neq\emptyset$. Finally, since $1$ is not in $(1,5)$ (i.e. its complement contains $1$ and thus is open), we know that it is close which means that **its closure is the same $\bf (1,5)$** and not $[1,5]$.

Comment: clearly understood, Thank you.